# Onclick for checkbox in typescript generates error

Tags: html, typescript, checkbox, angular-material, checked

I am generating checkboxes in a table (typescript) as follows:

```
  generateTable(): void {
    var table = document.getElementById("table1") as HTMLTableElement;
    if (table.childElementCount == 2) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        var newRow = table.insertRow(x+1);
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        newCell.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' onclick='toggleSelection()'>";
      }
    }
  }
```

```
toggleSelection() { 
    console.log("Test");
  }
```

Now, as soon as I click on either of the checkboxes, I receive the following console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleSelection is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):142:2)

I am not sure how to handle this error. It seems like the function "toggleSelection" is not properly defined. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems with your code:

1. Inserting dynamic code through `innerHTML` won't allow you to use event binding. Event binding only works with the template defined in your component;
2. You should not use `onclick`. Instead, you should use Angular’s event binding `(click)`. This allows Angular to call the function defined in your component.

With that in mind, I would recommend some changes in your code to make it work (it’ just a suggested approach):

1. Use `*ngFor` in your template instead of `innerHTML`:

   ```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Input</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <input type='checkbox' (click)='toggleSelection()'>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   ```
2. Create a public property in your component. I called it `items`:

   `public items: any = [];`
3. Change your `generateTable()` function. You only need to push new items to the `items` list and your template will automatically be updated. You can add your business rules here as well.

   generateTable(): void {
   this.items.push(1);
   }

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using now `<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox' (click)='toggleSelection()'>` to navigate to the respective function. How do I extract the information whether the checkbox is checked? The command
`document.getElementById('checkbox');` is not working as expected...

Comment: @User129599 update your input to: `<input type='checkbox' (click)='toggleSelection($event.target)'>`. `$event.target` allows you to get the propperties of the element. Update your `toggleSelection` function to: `public toggleSelection(value: any) { console.log(value.checked); }`. `value.checked` will be true or false. This way you can check whether the checkbox is checked or not.